# Problems regarding ARMA models and non stationarity

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity

I am struggling to find in easy terms what is the problem regarding nonstationarity of a time series and using  ARMA models on it (excluding "I"). If  we assume that the series is indeed a nonstationary AR(p) process would I get bad results if i just simple fit the time series using a AR(p) model ignoring the nonstationarity ?. Would the fit give bad point estimates or just not trusty variances and other stuff that may impact in prediction intervals for example, since  stationarity does not hold  (and MLE or OLS might need that assumption)? Finally can the model be good regarding its forecast power (withut prediction intervals) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would give bad point estimates, too. You can simulate a trajectory of a nonstationary AR(p) process with known parameter values and fit an AR(p) model. Do that many times and see how the point estimates compare to the true parameter values. I guess point forecasts would also be poor.

Comment: I did simulate some AR(1) and AR(2) processes but I got coeff almost identical to the real ones ( e.g. 1 for  AR(1) with unit root) so I cant see the problem so far

Comment: In the unit root case, for sufficiently long time series, you should be getting coefficients that have the Dickey-Fuller distribution rather than the normal distribution. In the explosive case, that would be something else but again not normal and likely biased.

Comment: Since I am not seeing problems in the point parameters estimates, could I use  such models for forecasting leaving aside the inference, or  if I differentiate I should get better results ? I am struggling mostly because the coefficients seems to be well estimated regardless of the nature of the time series.

Answer (score 0):

It would give bad point estimates, too. Consequently, point forecasts would also be poor. You can simulate a trajectory of a nonstationary AR(p) process with known parameter values and fit an AR(p) model. Do that many times and see how the point estimates compare to the true parameter values.

Here is a simple simulation showing that point estimates of the slope coefficients in a unit-root AR(1) model (a.k.a. a random walk) are biased (and do not follow a normal distribution asymptotically):

```r
m=1e3 # number of simulations
n=1e3 # length of time series
bhat=rep(NA,m) # for saving estimates of the slope coefficient
for(i in 1:m){
 set.seed(i); eps=rnorm(n)
 x=cumsum(eps)
 bhat[i]=coef(lm(x[-1]~x[-n]))[2]
}
par(mfrow=c(2,1)); plot(density(bhat),main="Density of bhat"); hist(bhat); par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is well known and perhaps boring for many, but I have decided to replicate it here since the OP was apparently not able to obtain the result independently.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I see the bias and non normal dis, in the end if I got it right, I should not fit arma for nonstationarity since  I might get bad estimates and thus bad forecasting capabilities. Do you know a proper book that might help me more into this or explicitly explain the things you are telling me here.

Comment: @tsjm, check out [these threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series%2breferences?tab=Votes) for numerous references and pick the one you like.

Comment: Thanks Richard, regarding my question above, and AR model fitted in a non stationary data would lead to bias and non normal distrobution of the coeff, but  leaving inference aside, does it means it wont work for forecast ? I see the non normal distr but the values are super close to one, so it will probably work for forecast,  at least for 1 period ahead

Comment: @tsjm, you can modify my simulation to see that for yourself. Or if I find the time later on, I might do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I dont use R but I will try to do it on python in the meantime

Comment: @tsjm, unfortunately, I am still too busy to extend the simulation, but perhaps you have got some progress on your own?

Comment: I did simulate some and also found some info about the bias associated with the estimators (even for stationary ARMA models). I just struggle i think to clearly see the fails in the forecasts because when i simulate a stationary and a non stationary process I get similar results regarding forecasts metrics.